# Updating quiver 3D points in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I am trying to use matplotlib to graph a 3D tree. I want a user to be able to drag each node around so that they can view the tree in any manner they choose. My plan is to eventually subclass in order to add data to the nodes and create the tree.

I am having trouble updating the graph while they are dragging the nodes around. I found a way to update the position of the scatter points using:

```
self.plot.set_offsets([x,y])  
self.plot.set_3d_properties([z], 'z')
```

But cannot seem to find a way of also updating the position and vector of the quivers.

I am also having difficulties with retrieving the mouse position which currently I always find:

```
ecoor == {'elevation': 30.0, 'azimuth': -60.0}
```

EDIT: Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest instead of trying to update the plot I removed it and made a new one.

```
# PlotNode._plot changes
self.plot.remove()
self.plot = axes.scatter([x], [y], [z])

# PlotInterNode._plot changes (both vector updates)
arlen=length(xc - x, yc - y, zc - z)
edge.remove()
edge = axes.quiver(x, y, z, xc - x, yc - y, zc - z, length=arlen,
                   arrow_length_ratio=.5/arlen, pivot='tail')
self.edges.update({childname:(childnode, edge)})
```

Here is the original code:

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class PlotNode(object):
    """
    Class for graph node.
    """

    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        """
        Initializes PlotNode.
        """
        self.__name__ = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.coordinates = self._make_coordinates()
        x, y, z = self.coordinates
        self.plot = axes.scatter([x], [y], [z])
        self.pressed = False
        self.move = False

    def name(self):
        return self.__name__

    COOR = (0, 0, 0)
    def _make_coordinates(self):
        """
        Finds coordinates from a file or, if not exist, calculate new coordinates.
        """
        if PlotNode.COOR[1] == PlotNode.COOR[0]:
            PlotNode.COOR = (PlotNode.COOR[0] + 1, 0, 0)
        elif PlotNode.COOR[2] == PlotNode.COOR[1]:
            PlotNode.COOR = (PlotNode.COOR[0], PlotNode.COOR[1] + 1, 0)
        else:
            PlotNode.COOR = (PlotNode.COOR[0], PlotNode.COOR[1], PlotNode.COOR[2] + 1)
        return (PlotNode.COOR[0], PlotNode.COOR[1], PlotNode.COOR[2])

    def _plot(self):
        """
        Plots node onto graph.
        """
        x, y, z = self.coordinates
        #updates the plot coordinates
        self.plot.set_offsets([x,y])
        self.plot.set_3d_properties([z], 'z')
        #updates the parent
        if self.parent:
            self.parent._plot(self.name())
        self.plot.figure.canvas.draw()

    def press(self, event):
        """
        Mouse press event.
        """
        if event.inaxes != self.plot.axes or not self.plot.contains(event)[0]:
            return False
        self.pressed = True
        axes.disable_mouse_rotation() #Make sure node moves instead of plot rotation
        return True

    def release(self, event):
        """
        Mouse release event.
        """
        if event.inaxes != self.plot.axes or not self.pressed:
            return False
        self.pressed = False
        if self.move:
            self.move = False
            x, y, z = self.coordinates
            ecoor = to_dict(axes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata))
            xe, ye, ze = ecoor.get('x', x), ecoor.get('y', y), ecoor.get('z', z)
            self.coordinates = (xe, ye, ze)
            self._plot()
        else:
            self.open()
        axes.mouse_init() #Make plot rotation avaliable again
        return True

    def motion(self, event):
        """
        Mouse motion event.
        """
        if event.inaxes != self.plot.axes or not self.plot.contains(event)[0]:
            return False
        if not self.pressed:
            return False
        self.move = True
        x, y, z = self.coordinates
        ecoor = to_dict(axes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata))
        xe, ye, ze = ecoor.get('x', x), ecoor.get('y', y), ecoor.get('z', z)
        self.coordinates = (xe, ye, ze)
        self._plot()
        return True

    def open(self):
        print('openned!') #to be changed

class PlotInterNode(PlotNode):
    """
    Class for graph folder node.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        """
        Initializes PlotDir.
        """
        self.edges = {}
        PlotNode.__init__(self, name, parent)

    def _plot(self, childname=None):
        """
        Plots node onto graph.
        """
        if childname:
            x, y, z = self.coordinates
            childnode, edge = self.edges.get(childname)
            xc, yc, zc = childnode.coordinates
            ##update the vector
            arlen=length(xc - x, yc - y, zc - z)
            ##update the arrow length
        else:
            x, y, z = self.coordinates
            for childname in self.edges:
                _, edge = self.edges.get(childname)
                ##update the position of each edge
            super()._plot()
        self.plot.figure.canvas.draw()

    def traverse(self):
        """
        Generator that traverses the tree rooted at this node.
        """
        yield self
        for child in self.edges:
            try:
                for node in self.edges.get(child)[0].traverse():
                    yield node
            except AttributeError:
                yield self.edges.get(child)[0]


def select_node(root, event):
    """
    Single event function to handle all node movement.
    """
    if event.name == 'button_press_event':
        event_fn = lambda self: PlotNode.press(self, event)
    elif event.name == 'button_release_event':
        event_fn = lambda self: PlotNode.release(self, event)
    elif event.name == 'motion_notify_event':
        event_fn = lambda self: PlotNode.motion(self, event)
    for node in root.traverse():
        if event_fn(node):
            return #if act on node then end

select_ids = []
def connect_select(root):
    """
    Connects select_node to events.
    """
    select_ids.append(figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',  lambda event: select_node(root, event)))
    select_ids.append(figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', lambda event: select_node(root, event)))
    select_ids.append(figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', lambda event: select_node(root, event)))

def to_dict(string):
    """
    Converts a string to a dictionary.
    """
    dictionary = {}
    for st in string.split(','):
        st = st.strip().split('=')
        if st[0] not in dictionary:
            try:
                dictionary.update({st[0]:float(st[1])})
            except ValueError:
                st[1] = st[1].split(' ')[0]
                dictionary.update({st[0]:float(st[1])})
    return dictionary

def length(x, y, z):
    """
    Returns hypotenuse.
    """
    ret = math.sqrt(math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2) + math.pow(z, 2))
    if not ret:
        ret = 1
    return ret

figure = pyplot.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
root = PlotInterNode('root')
def make_children(node, child_type, number):
    x, y, z = node.coordinates
    for i in range(number):
        child = child_type(str(i), node)
        xc, yc, zc = child.coordinates
        arlen = length(xc - x, yc - y, zc - z)
        edge = axes.quiver(x, y, z, xc - x, yc - y, zc - z, length=arlen, arrow_length_ratio=.5/arlen, pivot='tail')
        node.edges.update({child.name():(child, edge)})
def node_depth(node, depth):
    if not depth:
        make_children(node, PlotNode, 3)
    else:
        make_children(node, PlotInterNode, 3)
        for child in node.edges:
            node_depth(node.edges.get(child)[0], depth-1)
node_depth(root, 3)
connect_select(root)
pyplot.show()
```

EDIT: All I needed to retrieve the mouse position in 3D was add

```
axes.button_pressed = None
```

before I called

```
axes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
```

Comment: Just a comment on quivers: In general they cannot be updated. I think the only solution would be to redraw them every time.

Comment: Ah, that is dissapointing then :(
Good to know so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest instead of trying to update the plot I removed it and made a new one.

```
# PlotNode._plot changes
self.plot.remove()
self.plot = axes.scatter([x], [y], [z])

# PlotInterNode._plot changes (both vector updates)
arlen=length(xc - x, yc - y, zc - z)
edge.remove()
edge = axes.quiver(x, y, z, xc - x, yc - y, zc - z, length=arlen,
               arrow_length_ratio=.5/arlen, pivot='tail')
self.edges.update({childname:(childnode, edge)})
```

For the second part:
All I needed to retrieve the mouse position in 3D was add

```
axes.button_pressed = None
```

before I called

```
axes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
```